# Angular 17 SSR Express Server Providers

Tags: angular, typescript, server-side-rendering, angular-providers

I tried to share my request and response object to the angular application by defining Providers in the "server.ts" file.
Anyway, by injecting them into the app.component they are always undefined no matter if i am in the server or client context.

Does anybody know how to fix this behaviour? Sadly there isn't much information about it.

I didn't run the app in dev mode since angular currently ignores server.ts in devmode! - i builded it and served the express erver.

My tokens look like this:

```
export const REQUEST = new InjectionToken<Request>('REQUEST');
export const RESPONSE = new InjectionToken<Response>('RESPONSE');
```

My server looks like this:

```
  // All regular routes use the Angular engine
  server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('HI HI HI hi');
    const { protocol, originalUrl, baseUrl, headers } = req;
    /*const transferState = inject(TransferState);
    transferState.set(makeStateKey<any>('t'), JSON.stringify('hi'));*/
    commonEngine
      .render({
        bootstrap,
        documentFilePath: indexHtml,
        url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
        publicPath: browserDistFolder,
        providers: [
          { provide: RESPONSE, useValue: res },
          { provide: REQUEST, useValue: req }
          ],
      })
      .then((html) => res.send(html))
      .catch((err) => next(err));
  });
```

My Client  Injects the Injects the response object

```
  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(RESPONSE) private response: Response) {
    super();
  }
  ngOnClientInit() {
    console.log('RESPONSE', this.response);
    console.log('I am on client', this.communicationService.getValue('data'), this.token);
  }
```

No matter what i try, my Response is always null.

I googled and read the official documentation .

I am expecting the token to return a value!

Comment: Hi! I see you've tried using transferState in your server.ts file? Were you successful to pass the state to the client?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26323). ATM the devServer doesn't rely on the `server.ts` config.

Comment: well, i know that. but i builded the app and run tue server myself. so it should work but isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Disable prerender and works perfectly